# Matrix traversal optimization

Tags: c, matrix, optimization

Given a `n x n` matrix of `ints`, I have an algorithm that at each step of a for loop of range `n` traverses and modifies the matrix. Here is the code:

```c
typedef int **Matrix;

void floyd_slow(Matrix dist, int n)
{
    int d;

    for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
                if ((d=dist[k][j]+dist[i][k])<dist[i][j])
                    dist[i][j]=d;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        dist[i][i]=0;
}
```

The matrix is built as an array of `n*n` ints and for each index line `i`, `dist[i]` is the address of the row of index `i` [the above code is the [standard way](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm#C) to write the Floyd-Warshall algorithm but my question is not about this algorithm by itself].

The following drawing tries to explain how the matrix is processed:

[image: matrix processing]

At each step of the loop of index `k`, the underlying matrix is traversed line by line.

Now, consider the following transformation of the previous code:

```c
void relax(Matrix dist, int n, int* rowk, int* colk)
{
    int d;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            if ((d=rowk[j]+colk[i])<dist[i][j])
                dist[i][j]=d;
}

void floyd_fast(Matrix dist, int n)
{
    int i, k;

    int* colk=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    if (!colk)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        int* rowk =dist[k];

        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            colk[i]=dist[i][k];

        relax(dist, n, rowk, colk);
    }
    free(colk);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        dist[i][i]=0;
}
```

At every step, the elements of the matrix are accessed in the same order as in the previous algorithm.

The only difference is that at each step `k` in the exterior loop, the column of index `k` is **copied** into a temporary array, cf. the `colk` malloc above. It results that the element at position `(i, k)` is read from this array instead of being accessed directly from the matrix.

This innocuous change leads in fact to a significant speedup: you gain a factor 4 if n=1000.

I know that in C, it's faster to traverse an array in row major order but this is always the case here. So i was wondering why there is a speedup so important. Is it related to cache optimisation?

## Complete code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int **Matrix;

void floyd_slow(Matrix dist, int n)
{
    int d;

    for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
                if ((d=dist[k][j]+dist[i][k])<dist[i][j])
                    dist[i][j]=d;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        dist[i][i]=0;
}

void relax(Matrix dist, int n, int* rowk, int* colk)
{
    int d;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            if ((d=rowk[j]+colk[i])<dist[i][j])
                dist[i][j]=d;
}

void floyd_fast(Matrix dist, int n)
{
    int i, k;

    int* colk=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    if (!colk)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        int* rowk =dist[k];

        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            colk[i]=dist[i][k];

        relax(dist, n, rowk, colk);
    }
    free(colk);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        dist[i][i]=0;
}


void print(Matrix dist, int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%d ", dist[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void test_slow(Matrix dist, int n)
{
    clock_t now=clock();
    floyd_slow(dist, n);
//         print(dist, n);
    int *p=dist[0];
    free(dist);
    free(p);

    fprintf(stderr, "Elapsed slow: %.2f s\n",
            (double) (clock() - now) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

void test_fast(Matrix dist, int n)
{
    clock_t now=clock();
    floyd_fast(dist, n);
//         print(dist, n);
    int *p=dist[0];
    free(dist);
    free(p);
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Elapsed fast: %.2f s\n",
            (double) (clock() - now) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

int * data(int n)
{
    int N=n*n;
    int *t=malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    if (!t)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  

    srand(time(NULL)); 
    
    for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
        t[i]=(1+rand())%10;
        
    return t;    
}

Matrix getMatrix(int *t, int n)
{
    int N=n*n;
    int *tt=malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    Matrix mat=malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    
    if (!tt || !mat)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 

    memcpy(tt, t, N*sizeof(int));
    
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
        mat[i]=&tt[i*n];
    
    return mat;
}


int main(void)
{
    int n=1000;
    int *t=data(n);
    
    Matrix mat_slow=getMatrix(data(n), n);
    Matrix mat_fast=getMatrix(data(n), n); 
    
    test_slow(mat_slow, n);
    test_fast(mat_fast, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Elapsed slow: 0.58 s
Elapsed fast: 0.14 s
```

Compilation options:

```sh
rm floyd
gcc -Wall -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-parameter floyd.c -o floyd -lm
```

Comment: Given that you have working code, perhaps this is better suited for CodeReview.

Comment: Yes, the performance effect is likely due almost entirely to better cache use.